# Can't add Href to image in Javascript calls, inside Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am wondering how to add href link an image to next page in Javascript inside Jquery Mobile.

I am using the exact same code from my normal Jquery but it isnt working in my Jquery Mobile.

Wondering if it is possible to do so inside Jquery Mobile.

I am just trying load some dynamic images into Javascript via AJAX call, then add href to these images which it will click to the next html.

Thanks for your time!

```
<script>

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://test.com/App/testpic.php",
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $el = $('#list');
      var listView = new infinity.ListView($el);
      for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
        var listingid = data[i].listingid;
        var image = "http://test/image/"+data[i].pic;
        var myOtherUrl = "detail.html" + encodeURIComponent(listingid);
        var $newContent = "<li id=indi href='"+myOtherUrl+"'><img src='"+image+"'  width=100% ></img><li>" ;
        listView.append($newContent);
        var listItems = listView.find('.my-items');
        for(var index = 0, length = listItems.length; index < length; index++) {
          listItems[index].remove();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li` tag does not take an `href` attribute.  You also need an `a` tag.

```
    var $newContent = "<li id='indi'><a href='" + myOtherUrl + "'><img src='"
                       + image + " width='100%'/></a></li>" ;
```

(Note that you also needed a closing `</li>`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it working, but i don't know why it is slow. Takes about 2-3 seconds before it loads to the next html.

Comment: Almost certaily a network problem rather than anything to do with your browser.

Comment: But i tried packaging it into an app and test, and i switched all internet off, just to go to the next page thru the href, it still takes around 2-3 seconds to load, i am wondering if Href also have that 300ms delay as well from the single/double tap thing. And if i use hammer.js would that help

Comment: There is nothing peculiar to mobile about that code: run it in a browser and see if you get the same effect.